# Three.js Maya export error

Tags: javascript, python, three.js, maya

I'm trying to use this [Three.js exporter for Maya](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya).

However, when I try to load the `threeJsFileTranslator.py` plug-in from my plug-ins manager in Maya, it gives me an error in the Script Editor:

```
// Error: line 1: invalid syntax // 
// Warning: line 1: Failed to run file: D:/Maya/Maya2016/bin/plug-ins/threeJsFileTranslator.py // 
// Error: line 1:  (threeJsFileTranslator) //
```

I've tested this on both Maya 2016 and 2017 with no luck. No idea what causes this, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the file `D:/Maya/Maya2016/bin/plug-ins/threeJsFileTranslator.py` from what you downloaded from github? Look at what is on `Line 1` in that file, the source shows `__author__ = 'Sean Griffin'` is that the same in your file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by change the file? I don't think I altered the `D:/Maya/Maya2016/bin/plug-ins/threeJsFileTranslator.py` file in any way, I just copied it to that specific directory. Am I supposed to change something in it?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, yes I was just wondering if you had altered that file in anyway, and since you haven't then the problem sounds like python doesn't like something in `line 1` as invalid syntax..

Comment: I think I've seen this error before, when I run a python script accidentally as a mel script, maybe Maya is loading that script as a `mel` script and not a `python` script, hence the syntax error.

Comment: Perhaps. It's a bit odd though, since I'm able to run other python plug-ins without errors. However, this one plug-in does not work.

Comment: I tried running it as both a `mel` and `python` script. No luck, as I get this same error: `# Error: line 1: invalid syntax #`

Comment: Hm, maybe try commenting out those lines in the script that it's erroring at.. to see if that has any effect..

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either (same error). I'm guessing the problem is Maya and not the actual plug-in/script. Thank you for the help though, I think I'll just try to convert my scene to `JSON` with a different method, rather than exporting them using this script.

Comment: Sorry to hear you couldn't get it working. I assume you did the "installation" as listed here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya#installation. Only thing I can think of is "uninstall" the plugin (delete it), and "re-install" (copy file again), and restart Maya. Sorry we couldn't figure it out. Good luck bud :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the Maya three.js exporter. My solution was to use the three.js collada loader, A .dae file which retains all information about the model, storing it in an array which you can access by sifting through the array hierarchy. Everything is accessible, all elements—lights, shaders, shadows, except cameras. I preferred this method over the JSON method three.js uses. You can find the code example here:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

Exporting the model is relatively easy. Clean up your model by removing faces and irregular vertices. This will remove any issues you might run into in the future. You also need to make sure nothing has been `grouped` rather has to be `combined`. You can do this by opening the Outliner (Windows> Outliner) and select objects and organize them by name and whether they are within a group or not.  Otherwise, this causes difficulties when using a for loop to loop through the array/model when assigning shadows or any other bits of content

**To Export Model:**
Open your Maya Model. You can either export by selection or the entire file. In this instance, go under File > Export All. 
Maya has the plugin (not loaded) built in.

In the export panel, change the default export option that is set for you, to `DAE_FBX export` (Name may vary)

Once the export is complete, the model will be ready to link to your script.

The model can range from as little as 3MB to 50MB in size—and for the web that's big, but regardless you should always have a preloading screen available, just in case.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.